# python salesforce not connecting , home okay, work not. Firewall / Security?

Tags: python, security, networking, firewall

I registered my own salesforce developer login.

I am able to connect to this from my home computer and my work computer via the salesforce login url.

I am now writing python code to extract from salesforce. The code is below.

The code runs on my work laptop when I am at home and connected to my ISP.

When running the same code on my work laptop at work, (so now using work ISP), the code fails to connect.

## The error I get when I run at work is:

## requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.salesforce.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /services/Soap/u/40.0 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

So expect something going on with firewall and what not.

But am confused. It does not seem right that my work laptop is more "open" to outside when I use my ISP. I would have thought the security / firewall would have been implemented in a layer between work laptop and the ISP. So ISP agnostic. These laptops are meant to be used at home as well. I am not doing anything wrong in that respect.

Python code below.

```
import unicodecsv
from salesforce_bulk import SalesforceBulk

bulk = SalesforceBulk(password='**', username='**', security_token='**')

job = bulk.create_query_job("Contact", contentType='CSV')

batch = bulk.query(job, "select Id,LastName from Contact")

bulk.close_job(job)

while not bulk.is_batch_done(batch):

    sleep(10)

for result in bulk.get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch):

    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(result, encoding='utf-8')

    for row in reader:

        print(row) # dictionary rows
```

Oops. Figured it out. Need to add proxies parameter when connecting to salesforce at work. Bit of a revelation. There is a level of security/protection that is missing on a work laptop when it used at home. Did not realise that networks / firewall / security worked in such a way.

Comment: What do you mean by the "proxies parameter"?